# Objective c / iOS: How to override custom class's layoutSubviews in viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, class

I have created a custom UILabel class and set the default background color.
Here are .h and .m files of my custom class.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface imLabel : UILabel

@end
```

AND

```
#import "imLabel.h"

@implementation imLabel

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
}

- (void) layoutSubviews {

self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

}

@end
```

It works fine, but here is what I need: I want this work only if the backgroundColor is not set in ViewController.

Here is  my viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

label = [[imLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 300)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

[self.view addSubview:label];
}
```

Comment: Create a `Category` class from imLabel and call the method

Comment: I am new to iOS. Can You, please, tell me which method to call in category class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You control whether set label's backgroundColor  or not in ViewController, so the best way to meet your need that I think is check the label had set backgroundColor or not, if not then set it.

```
/* Somewhere in your ViewController */
if (!self.label.backgroundColor) {
    self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Comment: I need the vice versa of this. I want to override the default backgroundColor that is set in my custom class in my ViewController

Comment: I updated my question with my viewDidLoad code to make my question more clear.

Comment: Override the default backgroundColor that is set in my custom class in your ViewController? Why not set it to your target color directly in your ViewController? Then you don't have to override at all.

Comment: I have set it, but it still shows the color that is set in imLabel class.

Comment: You have set backgroundColor for label, so it always have backgroundColor.

Comment: Comment layoutSubviews method, then you get the backgroundColor set in ViewController.

Comment: There is noway to do the thing that i want? Maybe i must use another method not layoutSubviews?

Comment: if I comment that would not work for my further labels, whose backgroundColors i will not set :)

Comment: If you indeed need ,you can archive it like this: `- (void) layoutSubviews {
       if (!self.backgroundColor) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
`

}

Comment: I have tried this too. It works when I set the color in ViewController, but when I don't it doesn't get any color.

Comment: Interesting, delete all your other code in imLabel.m, then:`- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect { self = [super initWithFrame:aRect]; if (self) { self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; } }`

Comment: Error: Control reaches end of non-void function

Comment: `- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect { self = [super initWithFrame:aRect]; if (self) { self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; }  return self;}`

Answer (score 0):

Delete all your other code in imLabel.m, then:-

```
  (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect { self = [super initWithFrame:aRect]; if (self) { self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; } return self;}
```

Thanks to @Meiliang Dong